# How to get order details in custom order grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I have to create custom module,
in this module have a grid,
in this grid such as a some fields, like, order_id,product_name, etc
in that field how to get order data?

here is my Grid.php Code

```
<?php

class Mt_Wizardsports_Block_Adminhtml_Wizardsports_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('wizardsportsGrid');
        // This is the primary key of the database
        $this->setDefaultSort('wizardsports_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('wizardsports/wizardsports')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('wizardsports_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('wizardsports')->__('ID'),
            'align'     =>'right',
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'wizardsports_id',

        ));

        $this->addColumn('order_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('wizardsports')->__('Order ID'),
            'align'     =>'right',
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'order_id',
        ));


        $this->addColumn('product_name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('wizardsports')->__('Product Name'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'product_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('find_wizardsports', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('wizardsports')->__('How To Find Wizardsports?'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'find_wizardsports',
        ));



        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }


}
```

Comment: i want to get sales order data in this custom field grid

Answer (score 0):

Change your `_prepareCollection` method to

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
   $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
   $this->setCollection($collection);
   return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```